# ¿Cómo juntar varios case en un bloque switch de PHP?

Tags: php

En mi clase `Autoloader` no quiero cargar las clases del plugin `MonsterInsights`.

Estoy tratando de hacerlo así:

```
   class Autoloader 
   {
        public function __construct() 
        {
            spl_autoload_register(array($this, 'loader'));
        }
        private function loader($className) {
        //  include_once('LogTrace.class.php');
        //  LogTrace::log_trace();

            $str_path=realpath(dirname(__FILE__));
            $filename = $str_path .'/'. str_replace('\\', '/', $className) . ".class.php";


            switch ($filename)
            {

                case "MonsterInsights_GA_Lib_Http_Request.class.php": 
                    break;

                case "MonsterInsights.class.php":
                    break;

                case "MonsterInsights_GA_Lib_Utils.class.php":
                    break;

                default:
                    include($filename);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

**¿Cómo podría juntar todos los case en una lista de archivos ya que sólo me interesa incluir el archivo cuando no se llame como los tres... de los `case`?**

¿O me recomiendan otra solución mejor, teniendo en cuenta que todos los nombres de archivos que quiero evitar empiezan por `MonsterInsights`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se podría hacer de varias formas diferentes. Aquí dejo un par:

**Juntando todos los `case` en uno solo**

Si en un `switch` no se pone el `break`, continuará y ejecutará el siguiente caso. Entonces se podría hacer algo como esto, en el que todos los casos de "MonsterInsights" del `switch` original pasarán por uno solo:

```
        switch ($filename)
        {
            case "MonsterInsights_GA_Lib_Http_Request.class.php": 
            case "MonsterInsights.class.php":
            case "MonsterInsights_GA_Lib_Utils.class.php":
                break;
            default:
                include($filename);
                break;
        }
```

**Comprobando el inicio del nombre**

Si todos los ficheros que quieres excluir comienzan con "MonsterInsights", puedes hacer un `if` que compruebe que esa cadena no está al principio. El código se reduciría y, en mi opinión, sería más limpio y cubriría más casos (p.e. si en el futuro se incluye un nuevo fichero de MonsterInsights, no tendrías que modificar tu código).

Se haría así:

```
if (strpos($filename, 'MonsterInsights') != 0) {
    include($filename);
}
```

[`strpos`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.strpos.php) devuelve la posición de la primera ocurrencia de una cadena, si todos los ficheros que se quieren excluir comienzan con "MonsterInsights", bastaría con comprobar que el valor de strpos no es 0 (el inicio de la cadena).

Comment: Ahora mismo lo pruebo y te comento. De antemano gracias, sobre todo por la segunda opción, que me parece excelente.

Comment: Alvaro, el código parece funcionar, aunque negando el `if`, pues de lo contrario parece que sólo cargaría las clases que no quiero precisamente :) : `if (!strpos($filename, 'MonsterInsights') != 0) ...`. Por ahora me carga las otras clases, tengo que esperar a que se intente cargar alguna de MonsterInsights para ver qué pasa.

Comment: Ok. Deja que mire, ¿funciona con `!strpos(...)!=` o con `!strpos(...)==`? Esperaría lo Segundo

Comment: Funciona tal y como lo puse en el comentario : **`if (!strpos($filename, 'MonsterInsights') != 0)...`**

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que quieres que ocurra dentro del `if`? Lo he probado y parece funciona bien tal y como está en el código de la respuesta: si el fichero no comienza por MonsterInsights se incluye.

Comment: Dentro del if quiero que incluya los archivos cuyo nombre no empiece por `MonsterInsights`. Si lo pongo como dices en la respuesta no me funciona, cuando abro alguna página que usa `Autoloader` da error, pero si niego el `!strpos`  entonces sí funciona.

Comment: Es raro, a mí me funciona. Quizás sea porque `strpos` puede devolver `false` y confundirse con 0 dependiendo de la configuración. Prueba a hacer algo `$pos = strpos($fichero, "MonsterInsights"); if ($pos === false || $pos > 0) { include($fichero) }`.

Comment: Como has indicado en tu último comentario funciona. En cuanto a lo anterior, el `var_dump(strpos($filename, 'MonsterInsights') != 0);` retorna: `bool(false)` cuando el nombre del archivo no comienza por  `MonsterInsights`. Mientras que esto: `var_dump(strpos($filename, 'MonsterInsights') !== true);` devuelve `bool(true)`, y así funciona sin negar el `strpos`.

Comment: Sí que es raro. Quizás para evitar estos problemas también se podrían leer los primeros 15 caracteres y compararlos con “MonsterInsights”. Algo así: `if (substr($fichero,0,15)!=“MonsterInsights”) {...}`

Comment: No Alvaro, creo que es algo lógico... aquí, `strpos($filename, 'MonsterInsights') !== true` cuando el nombre del archivo no es el de `Monster` devuelve `true` porque ya el true está negado en la evaluación: `!== true`, entonces se pueden hacer los include dentro del if. No es que la evaluación esté fallando en sí.